# How to trigger hudson job through "execute shell"?

Tags: shell, hudson

I want to write a shellscript, in which it git pulls the remote repository.
and if the local repository is **not up-to-date** then trigger the build of hudson job.

In further scenario :

1) where to link up this shellscript (my shellscript ".sh" file) in hudson. so that it gets executed periodically before build.

Is there a way in configure Job :
2) Adding "execute shell" build step in hudson? and writing my shellscript over here.

Please specify me with shellscript code too.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe you should just use Jenkins' Git plugin. Is there something you are trying to do that isn't covered by it?

Comment: I don't want to do it with Jenkins Git plugin.